# php login script not working and stops in the script

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

hi i am new with php and mysql and i am working with a website, i was reading some tutorials on how to create a login page, when i tried creating my own login page, seems that it stops in the script and doesnt proceed to the next page if login is successful

here is the code

```
master1.php
<form action="loginscript.php" method="post" name="loginform">
<table class="logintable">
<!-- username-->
<tr>
<td class="tdalignright"><strong>
Username:</strong>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"/>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- password -->
<tr>
<td class="tdalignright"><strong>
Password:</strong>
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pword" id="pword"/>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- login button -->
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td class="tdalignright">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</td>
</tr>

</table> 
</form>
```

here is the login script

```
loginscript.php
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="seelsdb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tblteacher"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$uname=$_POST['uname']; 
$pword=$_POST['pword']; 
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$uname = stripslashes($uname);
$pword = stripslashes($pword);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pword = mysql_real_escape_string($pword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE teacherEmail='$uname' and teacherPass='$pword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("uname");
session_register("pword"); 
header("location:schedule.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

and here is the next page after a successful login

```
schedule.php

<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(uname)){
header("location:master1.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
LOGIN SUCCESSFUL
</body>
</html>
```

i cant seem to trace the error, hope you guys can help... thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to login? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Also hopefully you've modified it for our benefit, but if not you should really change your database username from root with blank password.

Comment: Right after > $result=mysql_query($sql); run: echo mysql_error();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login script should be:

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="seelsdb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tblteacher"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$uname=$_POST['uname']; 
$pword=$_POST['pword']; 
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$uname = stripslashes($uname);
$pword = stripslashes($pword);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pword = mysql_real_escape_string($pword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE teacherEmail='".$uname."' and teacherPass='".$pword."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
 echo 'Mysql did not respond to query'.mysql_error();
}
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("uname");
session_register("pword"); 
header("location:schedule.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

However, I will STRONGLY suggest you to opt for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql_* functions. If you are comfortable also refer to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i solved it a few moments ago, i changed session_register("uname") and session_register("pword") with $_SESSION($uname)=$uname and $_SESSION($pword)=$pword

Comment: +1 for the research! However, I will still encourage you to use MySQLi . Also, you can refer to one of my tutorial here on YouTube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTPW_fTJNNk . Thank me later ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it... i just replaced session_register("uname") and session_register("pword") with $_SESSION($uname)=$uname and $_SESSION($pword)=$pword